# Java temp file over new sessions of project

Tags: java, r.java-file

I am working on project which needs setting of the project to be saved and when the program starts it should read the file from the settings. 
In windows I dont have permission to make the file where-ever I want. I dont want to make in the temp folder as it can be deleted after some time. Any idea where should i place the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the following:

http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm

Of these, I have seen the following being used:

```
user.home
user.dir
java.io.tmpdir
```

being used for temporary files. However, I would assume that *user.dir* would be safest to use, while *user.home* would be the most commonplace.

EDIT: It seems the common practice is to use user.home for files that will be reused by your app, when starting and restarting, while user.dir is more commonly used for temporary files.

So, I reccommend using:

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

As your java will have the permissions to read and write there, so you can never go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.getEnv("APP_DATA") if this some kind of user preference
Use System.getEnv("LOCA_APP_DATA") if it also related to the local system (ie, the computer it is running on).
Remember that this does not work on other platforms than Windows.
To have something really cross-platform, you can use System.getProperty("user.home") which points to the user home directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to store preferences, you don't need a file at all and should use the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html). No need to worry about permissions, cross-compatibility, etc.